# Xcode: Update the project products group with new product name

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, product, target

In the products group in Xcode, I have the library "libMyLib-mac.a" in red, even after I build for device because I have changed the product name of the library in the targets of the project to "libMyLib.a".

Now, how can I update Xcode to show the new product name?

(**Note:** when I change the name back with the -mac suffix, the library is built and shown as available in the products folder.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier than I expected...

1. Right click the project file in finder, and show package contents.
2. Open the project.pbxproj file in some text editor.
3. Replaced all occurrences of `-mac.a` with `.a`.
4. Everything is now in order.